# Can I store my RGE file (Entourage 2008) to an network drive?

Tags: email, ms-office

Can I store my RGE file (Entourage 2008) to an network drive instead of a local folder ?

Answer (score 1):

A .rge file is an Entourage archive file, and is used to store old emails.  This file can be stored anywhere: your hard drive, a network drive, a thumb drive, burnt to CD, whatever.  If you need to access that archive again, you can import it into Entourage from wherever you've stored it by using the Import command.